# How can I read the Windows 8 licence key with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8, uefi

I have a dual boot windows 8 and Ubuntu on my Laptop.

Is it possible to read the Windows licence key under ubuntu? (I guess it is hidden in the Windows registry somehow)

Comment: Is it a UEFI system, If so, It's probably in the UEFT Key memory?

Comment: Yes, it is an UEFI System. I already found it and posted the ansewer below ;)

Comment: Reviewers: This is not off-topic. It is about using Ubuntu to find information in a Windows installation. Perfectly fine.

Comment: Agreed, this is on-topic, *especially* considering it appears that this may *really* be about reading ACPI information from firmware storage: this information isn't even stored inside what most of us would think of as the Windows system.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/637971/how-do-i-get-out-my-embedded-windows-8-key-from-a-linux-environment). The key seems to be stored in the ACPI-firmware:

```
sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
```

Which gave me the following results:

```
MSDMU
LENOVOCB-01   
ACPI
#####-#####-#####-#####-#####
```

(I replaced the product key with `#`)

pipe into `| tail -n1` if you need only the key as output.

Comment: That may be Lenovo specific to have the key in the firmware.  My work computers (Dell Laptop and Compaq Desktop) have a SLIC, but no MSDM.  Admittedly, both these computers predate Windows 8 by a few years.

Comment: On newer Dell PCs, that table actually exists. I have found it on two Dell Precision T1700 desktops from june 2014.

Comment: This worked great on a Lenovo Yoga3.

Comment: Worked on my UEFI Acer Aspire V. So it applies to other UEFI systems.

Answer (score 3):

If your HD is broken and need to install on a new HD or just want to know the key without an HD, this may help you:

```
sudo acpidump > myhiddenkey.txt
```

after that, search in your HOME folder the .txt file you just created. Press F3 to search within the file the word "MSDM" and bingo!

If you do not have `acpmdump` yet, time to install it using

```
sudo apt-get install acpidump
```

It worked on my Live pendrive of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Positivo notebook. The key was of a Windows 8 Single-language.

Comment: Ops, i forgot. The reason to output on a txt file is because the terminal window may not support so many lines of text.

Comment: The result is some 8 lines after the occurrrence of "MSDM" so this will show the key: `sudo acpidump|grep MSDM -A8` without using a textfile

Comment: `acpidump` has the option  `-n` to select only one part. This will output the key in one line:  `sudo acpidump -n msdm | cut -c58-|xargs|tr -d " " `

Comment: is there a way to know which version of windows it belongs to? 8 or 8.1? or it doesn't matter? I don't want to use 3rd party checkers

Comment: any help doing this with acpidump in FreeBSD? the tool is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

Got another one to add on to the last command that helped me:

```
sudo acpidump|grep MSDM -A6|cut -c58- |xargs | tr -d " " | grep -oP '[^.]+$'
```

I'm not sure if the string is definitely at the end, but that's how I extracted the key itself.

Comment: Always treat your answer as the only true answer. 

Comment: To make this a good answer, add that the exact position could differ on other systems. This will select exact 6 lines after finding MSDN in the output, which is in HEX

Comment: you can use `acpidump -n msdm` instead of `sudo acpidump|grep MSDM -A6`

Answer (score 1):

A slight refinement on the accepted answer. This will only print the key:

```
sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM | grep .*-.*-.*-.*-.*
```

Comment: better use `sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM |tail -n1` (in the rare case your vender name fits to your grep regex)